# C++ write data on array in file

Tags: c++, arrays, file, program-entry-point, ostream

i want write this data on array in file with c++ code
please help me with it !
this code is good but i want to write it on array !
what should i add to write it on array !

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
            ofstream file("BooksList.txt");
        if (file.is_open()){

                   file <<"[1]Programming Languages:Principles and Practice\t\tKenneth C. Louden\t\t\t0534953417"<<endl;
                   file <<"[2]Programming Languages:Principles and Paradigms\t\tAllen Tucker and Robert Noonan\t\t0071122800"<<endl;
                   file <<"[3]File Structures:An Object-Oriented Approach with C++\t\tMichael Folk and Bill Zoellick\t\t0201874016"<<endl;
                   file <<"[4]Data Structures Using C++\t\t\t\t\tD.S Malik\t\t\t\t0324782012"<<endl;
                   file <<"[5]Fundamentals of Web Development\t\t\t\tRandy Connolly\t\t\t\t0133407152"<<endl;
                   file <<"[6]Data Structures and Algorithms in Java\t\t\tGoodrich and Tamassia\t\t\t0471738840"<<endl;

            cout<<"written successfully !";

         }else{
              cout<<"File Not Found !- ERROR";
            }

          return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "write this data on array in file"?

Answer (score 0):

```
ofstream file;
file.open("BooksList.txt");
```

After this you can do file << "data"

Comment: But I'm really not sure if this was your question since you are talking about arrays too.